# How do you create a share link for a document in Sharepoint through Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to create an anonymous link (it's OK if it times out after N number of days) from a file which is in SharePoint Online.

The documentation below seems to work for `/me/` folders which are OneDrive for Business basically.

Is there no way of [creating a share / anonymous link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createlink) from a file stored in SharePoint?

Comment: As long as you can create a Graph URL that references an item you should be able to create links. You're correct that /me addresses a user's personal ODB, but you can also use /drives/<id> to access a document library in a non-personal site. What identifying information do you have to address the item you want to create a link for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm way too late to help you, but as I just wasted 2.5 hours to get this done, here's the trick :

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{tenantName}.sharepoint.com,{siteCollectionId},{webId}/lists/{listId}/items/{itemId}/driveitem/createLink
```

With body :

```
{"type":"view","scope":"anonymous"}
```

---

`{sitecollectionId}` : Can be obtained via `{siteCollectionUrl}/_api/site/id`

`{webId}` : Can be obtained via `{webUrl}/_api/web/id`

`{listId}` : Can be obtained in URL from the list settings page

`{itemId}` : Can be obtained by displaying the "ID" field in the current view

---

- How to get the DriveItem from a ListItem : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0
- How to build a share link for a DriveItem : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: I hope it was for good reason :) Here's your green tick!